# Java Script for of

Tags: javascript

Can you explain me, please, why first console.log shows me array with both:
array.foo and item, but when I use for of loop it does not show array.foo?

```
let array = [3,5,8, item = 'good'];
array.foo = 'hello';
console.log(array);

for (var i of array) {
 console.log( i);
}
```

Comment: because, although both `item` and `foo` are _properties_ of `array`, they are not _enumerable properties_

Comment: the `for (var variable of array){}` syntax with arrays only loops over the numeric indices, not the properties of the array object

Comment: @Hamms: `item` is a variable. `'good'` is an array element (and the value of an enumerable property that will be iterated). `.foo` is an enumerable property that does not get iterated because it's not an array index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`for-of` runtime semantics](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements-runtime-semantics-labelledevaluation) tell us that we will iterate over `ForIn/OfHeadEvaluation( « », AssignmentExpression, iterate)`. [Which](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofheadevaluation-tdznames-expr-iterationkind) in turn returns us the `GetIterator(exprValue)` (see 8.b). [`GetIterator`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-getiterator) returns an iterator from the `@@iterator` slot (or `Symbol.iterator`). [Which for an array](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype-@@iterator) returns the [`Array.prototype.values`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.values) which uses [`CreateArrayIterator`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createarrayiterator) whose semantics are defined [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-%25arrayiteratorprototype%25-object).

And as you can see at [`%ArrayIteratorPrototype%.next( )`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-%25arrayiteratorprototype%25.next) it iterates through the indexes from `0` through `length - 1` and says nothing about other properties.

So, to summarise, the `for-of` does not iterate through non-index properties because the array iterator does not do so.